# Refresh table option is not available for Tabular Editor 3

Tags: ssas-tabular, tabular-editor

Some time ago the refresh table option has disappeared from my menu in Tabular Editor 3.10.01 Enterprise edition.

I tried to reset all my toolbars, menus and settings. Also, reinstalled Tabular Editor 3 several times, but still, when I right-click on table in my model, I don't see option to refresh it (the same when I go to Table tab, it is not present there).

Comment: Don't have TE3, but maybe the table is DirectQuery and not Import?